# Search elastic search for Ids ending with specific string

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I ingested documents of this simplified format:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I can loop/scroll over all documents using this:

```
client.Search<Document>
(
    scr => scr.Index(IndexName)
        .From(0)
        .Size(100)
        .MatchAll()
        .Scroll(scrollTimeout)
)
;
```

Is it possible to only focus on documents where the Ids end with a specific string - e.g.: bla?

I tried this:

```
return client.Search<Document>
(
    scr => scr.Index(IndexName)
    .From(0)
    .Size(100)
    .MatchAll()
    .Scroll(scrollTimeout).Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
        .Field(f => f.Id)
        .Query("bla")
        )
    )
)
;
```

Also tried:

```
return client.Search<Document>
(
    scr => scr.Index(IndexName)
    .From(0)
    .Size(100)
    .MatchAll()
    .Scroll(scrollTimeout).Query(q => q
        .MoreLikeThis(sn => sn
        .Fields(ff => ff
            .Field(f => f.Id)
)
```

Using wildcard also does not work:

```
return client.Search<Document>
(
    scr => scr.Index(IndexName)
    .From(0)
    .Size(100)
    .MatchAll()
    .Scroll(scrollTimeout).Query(q => q
        .Wildcard(c => c
        .Name("named_query")
        .Boost(1.1)
        .Field(p => p.Id)
        .Value("bla")
        .Rewrite(MultiTermQueryRewrite.TopTermsBoost(10))
        )
    )
)
;
```

Please note that this works with other fields. So my current hunch is, that something like this just does not work for Ids.

Filip Cordas suggested the use of regex. This also does not work:

```
return client.Search<Document>
(
    scr => scr.Index(IndexName)
    .From(0)
    .Size(1000)
    .MatchAll().Scroll(scrollTimeout).Query(q => q
        .Regexp(c => c
        .Field(p => p.Id)
        .Value("bla$")
        )
    )
)
;
```

As requested by Russ Cam. I tried the following, which also did not work:

```
var searchResponses = client.Search<Document>
(
    scr => scr.Index(indexName)
        .From(0)
        .Size(1000)
        .Query(q => q.Regexp(c => c
            .Field(p => p.Id)
            .Value("bla$")
        )
   )
)
;
```

Comment: take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/more-like-this-full-document-query-usage.html

Comment: thanks. tried this but struggle tbh - get bad request error. could you please suggest code?

Comment: this might be more useful, also includes an example https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: try  .Query("*bla")

Comment: this does not work ...

Comment: Have you tried regex https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/regexp-query-usage.html. Also what sort of analyzer are you applying what usually happens is some strange tokenization happens so it doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the `.MatchAll()` call in the method chain. It's a shorthand for `.Query(q => q.MatchAll())` that _could_ be affecting the resultant JSON query. What do you see if you output the serialized query? You can get it a number of ways: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging.html

Comment: @RussCam tried this but no luck. I think id columns cannot be searched ...

Comment: They can be searched. Can you edit your question and show the mapping for the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how performant will this be but should do what you want.

```
q
.Regexp(c => c
    .Field(p => p.Id)
    .Value("bla$")
)
```

This will return lower case terms that end with bla, if case sensitive strings are needed you ca do a case insensitive regex or apply a normalizer.
Also you could use the [reverse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-reverse-tokenfilter.html) token filter with an [n-gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.htm), should be the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but this does not work either. I edited my question and added this as another non working example.

Comment: @cs0815 Could you post the analyzer on the field and the ID example, regex is term based so it could be a tokenization issue

Comment: @cs0815 you should remove MatchAll